# i want to save a list in dictionary in a way that it will have a key and attribute

Tags: python

please help

```
value = 'http://localhost:8001/issues/load?project_name=react&since=2016-03-24&until=2017-03-25&state=closed&sort=created&direction=asc&per_page=100&labels=Type:%20Bug'
hashing = hash(value)
words = value.split('&')
for data in words:
    words2 = data.split('=')
    print(words2)
```

Comment: You should ask a question instead of just posting code.  Just having a title for your post and some code gives us no indication of what you're actually needing help with.

Answer (score 0):

Since `words2` has each split into two like:

```
['http://localhost:8001/issues/load?project_name', 'react']
['since', '2016-03-24']
['until', '2017-03-25']
```

Use that to add values to a dictionary:

```
>>> key_vals = {}
>>> for data in words:
...     words2 = data.split('=')
...     key_vals[words2[0]] = words2[1]
...
>>> pprint.pprint(key_vals)
{'direction': 'asc',
 'http://localhost:8001/issues/load?project_name': 'react',
 'labels': 'Type:%20Bug',
 'per_page': '100',
 'since': '2016-03-24',
 'sort': 'created',
 'state': 'closed',
 'until': '2017-03-25'}
```

And the assignment to `key_vals` can be reduced to:

```
key_vals = {key: val for (key, val) in [data.split('=') for data in words]}
```